# Trying to draw a basic shape with LWJGL3

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

so i want to draw a shape using VAO and VBOs and i think im doing everything right but whenever i run my code i just get the window with the clear color. I had an issue before when i tried to initialize the triangles before i called create capabilities, am i missing some function to start drawing?

here is my code:

```
int vaoId, vboId, vertexCount;

float[] vertices = {
    // Left bottom triangle
    -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,};

private void init() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to Initialize GLFW!");
    }

    int width = 1000;
    int height = 1000;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "App", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create Window!");
    }

    GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width() - width) / 2, (videoMode.height() - height) / 2);

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

private void loop() {
    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    initTriangle();

    // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
    // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

        // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
        // invoked during this call.
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
}

private void initTriangle() {

    FloatBuffer vertBuf = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(vertices.length);
    vertBuf.put(vertices);
    vertBuf.flip();

    vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

    vboId = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I hope you guys can help, thanks a lot.

Comment: What shaders are you using?

Comment: Here is the [most basic LWJGL program.](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)  Get it working then try to modify it one small step at a time to do what you want.  When something breaks, stop right there, post here at SO and explain exactly what you changed to make it not work. https://www.lwjgl.org/guide

Comment: I am not using shaders. Is that my problem?. And is it a necessity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not using shaders. Is that my problem? And is it a necessity

The state of the art way of rendering in OpenGL, would be to use a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader).

If you don't use a shader, than you have to define the array of vertex data by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)

```
vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

vboId = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 ); // <---------------

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

and you have to enable the client-side capability for vertex coordinates by [`glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY )`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml):

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY ); // <---------------

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY ); // <---------------
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

---

Note, this state of the client-side capability (or  vertex attribute array) is stored in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
So it is sufficient to enable the vertex coordinates, when the vertex array object is specified. The enabling and disabling of the vertex coordinates, when drawing the geometry, can be omitted:

```
vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

vboId = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 ); 
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY ); // <---------------

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```